# Configuring the Linux system daemons "flush" and "kswapd"

Tags: system, daemon, flush

We have a heavy duty I/O node which transfers hundreds of giga bytes from disk to the network in each data transmission.  We observe that our transmission application almost halts when the "flush"'s and "kswapd"'s CPU utilization approaches 100%.

Can we increase the number of these 2 system daemon processes?
How do we change the behavior of them?  For example, changing the threshold system parameters which trigger the running of them.
Where are the executables and configuration files for them?

Many thanks!